# css, jquery : background image aimation

Tags: jquery, css

A large image (name of the image: **image.jpg**) will be used as a background of a `div`.

Part of the image (suppose 70%) will be visible and then the image will move slowly rightward. After the full of the remaining part becomes visible it will start moving leftward.

How to achieve that with cross browser compatibilities ?

Markup code:

```
<div class="my_div"></div>

<style type="text/css">
.my_div{
     background-image: url('/img/image.jpg');
 }
</style>
```

Comment: I just can't figure out any way ..

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed, check out the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) method of jQuery and try to animate the `background-position` property of the `.my_div` element.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, let me see

Comment: If you want css3, see this [move.js](http://visionmedia.github.com/move.js/).

Comment: @Vucko,  does that do any background image animation ?

Comment: @Vucko, if the OP wants CSS3 he should see a javascript library ?!?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, by the way, what does OP mean ?

Comment: OP = *Original Poster* (*that would be you in this case..*)

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed it's a libary that simplifies CSS3 transitions and transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/fwyJz/2/

```
$(function() {
   animate();
  setInterval(function() { animate();}, 7000);
});
function animate()
{
 $(".my").animate({
    backgroundPosition: "(-200px 0px)"
}, 3500, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "0px 0px"
    }, 3500).end();
});
}
```

​This uses a  js file : [jquery.bgpos](http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/jquery.bgpos.js)

Comment: suppose, I omit the second animate method and add the `backgroundPosition` line in the call back function, then a flicker is there when the background image is positioned to `0,0` again. How to remove the flicker please ? jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fwyJz/4/

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed : Yes , a sudden change in background position will make flicker.. and Why u want to omit second animate..?

Comment: I just want the animation to be leftward only. After the leftward animation the bg image should be in its original position (`0,0`) without any flicker and the leftward animation will follow. The thing is no rightward animation is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To place it do something like this

```
.my_div{
  background: url(img/image.jpg) no-repeat top right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

To animate simply animate the margins with jquery
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$(".my_div").animate({
    marginRight: "100px"
  }, 1500 );
```

I didn't test this but something like this should do the trick

To start it create a button with ID="button" and click it.

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="animate me" />
```

And the js

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $(".my_div").animate({
    marginRight: "100px"
  }, 1500 );
});
```

Comment: hmm, makes sense. let me try

Comment: how to start the leftward animation

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#block").animate({
    marginLeft: "100px"
}, 1500, function(){
    $(this).animate({
         marginRight: "100px"
    });
});
```